# uNFC write and read MifareClassic1k card

Tags: c#, nfc, mifare

hello i use https://github.com/ppatierno/unfc
i wanna write and read byte data data length is 208

my code :

```
                byte[] Template = new byte[208];
                for (int i = 0; i < Template.Length; i++)
                {
                    Template[i] = (byte)((byte)i + 1);
                }

                List<byte> Ekle = new List<byte>();
                int sira = 0;
                int blok = 5;
                string key = "";
                byte asd = 5;
               
                ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
                for (int i = 1; i < Template.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i % 16 == 0)
                    {

                        Ekle.Add(Template[sira]);
                        key = DecimalToHexadecimal(blok);
                        byte abc = Byte.Parse(key, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                        NfcMifareTagConnection mifareConn = (NfcMifareTagConnection)e.Connection;

                        mifareConn.Authenticate(MifareKeyAuth.KeyA, asd, new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF });
                      

                       
                        blok++;
                        sira++;
                        asd++;


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Ekle.Add(Template[sira]);
                        sira++;
                    }
                }
```

it shows written but then I can't read and write again

Comment: You are changing the key so you need to read file with new key and not old key.

Comment: why change key read

Comment: If you wrote data with a new key you have to read with the new key.  You are trying to decrypt data written with new key, but still using the old key.

Comment: I'm trying to read with the key I wrote. I can't change key.

Comment: You can't modify a key (dictionary).  New to create new instance or use an existing instance.

Comment: I didn't understand how to do it. can you write an example

Comment: Looks like key is in following code : https://github.com/ppatierno/unfc/blob/master/uNFC/NfcMifareTagConnection.cs

Comment: i use this but dont working

Comment: The write and read key has to be the same.  You need to figure out why the two keys are not matching.  I cannot help debug the problem. only tell you that the keys do not match.